# Create Custom Icon with Vuetify

Tags: icons, vuetify.js

I am trying to create a custom icon using Vuetify v-icon:
I follow the Docs but its doesnt work for me.

1. I create a component with svg code:
   HomeIcon.vue
   [image]
2. The vuetify.js looks like this:
   [image]

3)Now I am trying to use it in my component:
[image]

4. But the result is:
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you change your code in vuetify.js file it should be working fine.
another trick is to always add icons after theme if you have one obviously.

Change your code to this:

```
import icon from "icon.vue";
export default new Vuetify({
   theme,
   icons: {
     values: {
        icon: {
         component: icon,
         },
      },
     },
   });
```

You can also make a shortcut by doing $icon instead of $vuetify.icons.icon.